# Return object from while loop

Tags: r, while-loop

UPDATE see below

I am not sure how to populate a list or vector with elements in a while loop when there is no counter/iterator to index by. See below minimal example. I have a more complicated while loop that, like foo below, has a logical statement that doesn't include a number, so it's not clear to me how to populate the list vec with x. Is it possible to create some kind of iterator within the while loop so that each time you go through the while loop the iterator simply increases by one? I could then use this iterator to index the list vec?

```
foo <- function(){
  names <- list("a","b","c")
  vec <- list()
  more <- TRUE
  while(more == TRUE){
   names <- rep(names, 2)
   if(length(names) < 50) vec <- names
   more <- length(names) < 50
   }
  vec
}

foo()
```

Thanks, this seems to work as I wanted now:

```
foo <- function(){
  names <- list("a","b","c")
  i <- 0
  vec <- list()
  more <- TRUE
  while(more == TRUE){
    i <- i + 1
    names <- rep(names, 2)
    if(length(names) < 50) vec[[i]] <- names
    more <- length(names) < 50
  }
 vec
}

foo()
```

Comment: Also what does this have to do with returning an object from a while loop?

Comment: Oh, I was having problem returning the object from a while loop that is nested within a function. E.g., I couldn't return vec above from the function foo. But I think the above fixes this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the approach where you construct your own iterator is very easy.  Here is some example code that prints the numbers 1 through 10 in what could possibly be the least R like way to accomplish this task:

```
i <- 0
more <- TRUE
while(more == TRUE){
    i <- i + 1
    print(i)
    if(i == 10){
        more <- FALSE
    }
}
```

As you can see it's pretty much exactly like you describe.  You just increase the iterator at the top of the loop.

Comment: I always find `if (foo == TRUE)` or `while(foo == TRUE)` amusing. I was taught to write code like this in VB a few years ago and I kept on writing all my `if`'s in this way until one day I suddenly realized `if (foo)` was the same... :)

Comment: I agree that not including the extra "== TRUE" is better style.  Although they aren't quite exactly the same.  For instance using the extra check if for some reason if you wanted to instead of `more <- FALSE` you could do something like `more <- "some_output_diagnostics"` and it would still exit the loop.  Horrible style but it's not exactly the same and if you didn't do the other check it would cause an error instead of exiting the loop.